# SUM only distinct values given certain criteria SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, subquery

I have a table which Data is like

```
LayerID       Company id  Company name    Layer Name   Price
     1           1             x            x1          20
     2           1             x            x2          10 
     3           2             y            y1          50
     4           2             y            y2          50
     5           2             y            y3          50
     6           3             z            z1          15
```

What I want is to have the following table after SQL query is applied

```
Company id  Company name     Price
     1           x            30
     2           y            50 
     3           z            15
```

i.e. the following rules apply:

1. if the price for the different layers for the company are different then sum them up
   example: for company x it would be 20+10 = 30
2. if the price for the different layers for the company are the same then take that number
   example: for company y it would be 50, for z it would be 15

I'm not sure how i would so this in SQL (for Access/VBA), and have been trying to figure this out to no avail.

Thanks for your help in advance

Claudy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL query that would produce the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT m.Company_id, m.Company_name, SUM(m.Price)
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Company_id, Company_name, Price
  FROM MyTable 
) AS m
GROUP BY m.Company_id, m.Company_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as:

```
SELECT m.Company_id, m.Company_name, SUM(distinct m.Price)
FROM table m
GROUP BY m.Company_id, m.Company_name;
```

As a warning:  I *never* use `sum(distinct)`.  It generally indicates an error in the underlying data structure or subquery generating the data.

EDIT:

Why is it bad to do this?  Generally, what you really want is:

```
SUM(m.Price) where <some id> is distinct
```

But you can't phrase that in SQL without a subquery.  If the above is what you want, then you have a problem when two "id"s have the same price.  The `sum()` produces the wrong value.

Comment: I didn't know you could SUM distinct. Why is it so bad to do this?

Comment: *@Gordon Linoff*, I don't think `SUM(DISTINCT m.Price)` will work in MS Access.  I just tried your query and received the error: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Sum(DISTINCT m.Price)'`.